# How to make this one on my website's url?

Tags: url, ssl, https, web, ssl-certificate

[Sample Image for the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgldp.jpg)

I don't know what I will call this but I want to have like that on my website.

Answer (score 1):

To get a green address bar, you need to buy an Extended Validation SSL certificate. You usually can get one from your domain name registrar.